# Is there a way to listen to the `onload` events of `src` attributes? (A-frame)

Tags: javascript, aframe

Is there a way to listen to the `onload` events of `src` attributes? I can't use `<a-assets>` because I'm using an `<a-sky>` because `<a-assets>` don't seem to work with `<a-sky>`. And tried loading the images of `<a-assets>` and `<a-sky>` simultanously, but one image loads first and then the other, which means that the loading time is doubled.

What's the proper way of listening to the `src` attribute? So I can perform an action when the image in it has loaded?

(I want to avoid having an blank scene while the image on the `src` of the `<a-sky>` is loading.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a `load` event equivalent that works here, but `<a-assets/>` is supposed to work in this case. If the shorthand `<a-sky/>` doesn't work with assets, you can use the longer form:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <img id="my-asset" src="https://..." crossorigin="anonymous">
  </a-assets>
  <a-entity geometry="primitive: sphere;
                      radius: 5000;"
            material="src: #asset-id;
                      side: back;">
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

> Note: I don't know why `crossorigin="anonymous"` is necessary. It probably shouldn't be, but it is as of 08/07/16.

Answer (score 5):

Like Don said, use the `crossorigin` flag on the asset to get it working with your `<a-sky>`.

Once you have that, you can listen to `img.onload`/`loaded` like you would with a normal DOM event. Below I wrap some code inside an A-Frame component that automatically hooks into the scene:

```
<script>
  // Do something on asset load.
  AFRAME.registerComponent('do-on-asset-load', {
    schema: {
      src: {type: 'selector'}
    },

    init: function () { 
      var el = this.el;
      var assetEl = this.data.src;
      assetEl.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Do something with your element.
      });
    }
  });
</script>

<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <img id="my-asset" src="https://..." crossorigin="anonymous">
  </a-assets>
  <a-sky src="#my-asset" do-on-asset-load="#my-asset"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

If you weren't using assets, you'd have to reach into the material to grab the internally-created image:

`document.querySelector('a-sky').components.material.material.map.image`

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:  *"If the additional-layers of 'A-Frame or what-have-you' did not exist, could you attach a DOM event-handler to *"an **attribute** of"* something?"

The answer would be "No":    **"DOM *objects"*** generate and receive events, but their *attributes* do not.

Therefore, 'A-Frame or what-have-you,' being necessarily *built on top of* these things and therefore wholly dependent upon it, by-definition "can do no more (or less)."